# How to convert vtkpolydata into vtkimagedata?

Tags: c++, vtk

In vtp ( or xml? ) files I have a set of points with position (x,y,z), mass (m) and densities (rho) for each points.

They look like so

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="PolyData" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian" header_type="UInt32" compressor="vtkZLibDataCompressor">
  <PolyData>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="524288"               NumberOfVerts="0"                    NumberOfLines="0"                    NumberOfStrips="0"                    NumberOfPolys="0"                   >
      <PointData>
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="vx" format="appended" RangeMin="-10617.716797"        RangeMax="11650.322266"         offset="0"                   />
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="vy" format="appended" RangeMin="-12008.198242"        RangeMax="11676.560547"         offset="2554076"             />
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="vz" format="appended" RangeMin="-10880.447266"        RangeMax="11361.508789"         offset="5104080"             />
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="mass" format="appended" RangeMin="0.16916139424"        RangeMax="0.83083856106"        offset="7655432"             />
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="uu" format="appended" RangeMin="0"                    RangeMax="117252.91406"         offset="7742064"             />
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="hh" format="appended" RangeMin="0"                    RangeMax="4.1185030937"         offset="8877700"             />
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="mu" format="appended" RangeMin="1.2307692766"         RangeMax="1.2307692766"         offset="10032668"            />
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="rho" format="appended" RangeMin="0"                    RangeMax="49503150080"          offset="10038236"            />
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="phi" format="appended" RangeMin="-1.3579902649"        RangeMax="1.2645899057"         offset="11265024"            />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="id" format="appended" RangeMin="0"                    RangeMax="524287"               offset="13840232"            />
        <DataArray type="UInt16" Name="mask" format="appended" RangeMin="0"                    RangeMax="3"                    offset="15044924"            />
      </PointData>
      <CellData>
      </CellData>
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Points" NumberOfComponents="3" format="appended" RangeMin="0.89113022864"        RangeMax="110.020575"           offset="15133592"            />
      </Points>
      <Verts>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="22080132"            />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="22080148"            />
      </Verts>
      <Lines>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="22080164"            />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="22080180"            />
      </Lines>
      <Strips>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="22080196"            />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="22080212"            />
      </Strips>
      <Polys>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="22080228"            />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="22080244"            />
      </Polys>
    </Piece>
  </PolyData>
  <AppendedData encoding="base64">
      ...
  </AppendedData>
</VTKFile
```

I would like to use this to do some volume rendering, therefore I need to have it as ImageData.

My first stupid approach is this : using a `vtkXMLImageDataReader` instead of a `vtkXMLPolyDataReader`. It obviously didn't work.

What can I do to convert it to `ImageData` or make it work with any volumeMapper?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With `vtkplotter` you can create a vtkVolume interpolating from a sparse set of points:

```py
from vtkplotter import *

mymesh = ... # vtkPolyData with pointdata

vol = interpolateToVolume(Actor(mymesh))

#write(vol, 'output.vti')

show(vol)
```

see [here](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter/blob/master/examples/volumetric/interpolateVolume.py).

Comment: is it possible to do that but in C++?

Comment: Yes, sure, but you will have to dig into the python code and translate it into c++, which may not be very difficult to do: https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter/blob/f8c1d8449e694dc7e6b896b53548d9d2e7e1ffba/vtkplotter/analysis.py#L1680

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something in the question. But from my understanding, you can simpy follow this example: [link](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/PolyDataToImageData)